# Why I cannot mount ISO file from this .desktop file by `fuseiso`?

Tags: .desktop, xdg

I want to mount iso files without root permission by `fuseiso`, and this is how to mount a iso file:

```
fuseiso -p '/path/to/isofilename' '/media/isofilename'
```

, so I make a .desktop file followed [Freedesktop Standard (The Exec key)](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) as bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mount ISO image
Name[zh_TW]=掛載光碟映像檔
Exec=fuseiso -p %U "/media/$(basename %U)"
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/x-cd-image
```

, but it failed.

I think it failed because of `$(basename %U)`, if it is changed to a fixed string, the iso file can be mounted.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very easy fix is the following:

Make a custom script of yours and inside the desktop file make it be:

`/home/kevin/Documents/Scripts/orWherever/myCustomScript.sh %U` (or whatever the path to your custom script is; don't forget to make it executable)

and inside the custom script of yours call

```
#!/bin/bash
fuseiso -p $1 "/media/$(basename $1)"
```

Edit:

Explanation of why it doesn't work the way you tried:

The `$(command here)` in order to take the output of the `basename` command, is a `bash` thing and it doesn't work by default everywhere. The `Exec` field expects an executable file and (optionally) can pass parameters to it. In fact, `%U` [isn't the only thing that is supported](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables). That's why something that would work in a bash script doesn't always work in such a case.

Comment: Good answer! but why can't I use `baseline` for the Exec key in .desktop file?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Appreciate your explanation. :-)